# Regex in Notepad++ like sed

Tags: regex, sed, notepad++

In linux sed, we can use the matched regex using "&". Can i do the same in notepad++ ? in find and replace, can i use the matched string by regex to be used in replace section ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update

Notepad++ version 6.x has been released, using PCRE as its regex engine for find-and-replace. You can now refer to the entire match in the replacement string using `$0` or `$&` (but not `\&` or `&`), without having to capture the entire pattern anymore.

For example, replacing `foo` with `$&bar$&` yields `foobarfoo`.

---

#### Old answer

There isn't a way to do this in Notepad++ regex I'm afraid. You have to manually capture the entire pattern and use `\1` in the replacement field.

As an example, for the following sed command:

```
sed s/foo/\&bar\&/
```

Which outputs `foobarfoo` for the input string `foo`, the equivalent in Notepad++ regex is:

Find:

```
(foo)
```

Replace with:

```
\1bar\1
```

Comment: sorry i didnt get it, can you provide a simple example, pls dont mind just need a bit help

Comment: i didnt get why you said its not possible in notepad++, where i can use the /1. I mean, it does the same thing like "&" isnt it ?

Comment: @user1068846: No, when you use `\1` you need to add the brackets to the whole string, like I did with `(foo)`. You don't need to wrap the whole pattern in brackets in sed.

Comment: So thats the only difference right, i can add brackets :-) thanks alot sir

Comment: In my version of sed `echo foo | sed s/foo/\&bar\&/` returns `&bar&` which is what I would expect as the `&` does not need to be escaped unless you want to return `&`.

Comment: @potong: Mine needs to be escaped unless I quote the entire pattern `sed 's/foo/&bar&/'`. Wonder if it's a version or OS difference (I'm on a Mac).